# How to limit table rows per page using PDFsharp?

Tags: c#, foreach, pdfsharp

I am using a table to display legend data. The page is in landscape mode. I would like to limit the table rows to 15 per column. 2 columns per page and then a new page is created, and so on. This is the current output.
[image: currentoutput]

Here is a mockup of what I would like it to look like when there is more data. If more than 30 items then a new page needs to be created.
[image: whatIneedittolooklike]

Code in controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public PDF Post([FromBody]List<Data> data)
    {

        try
        {
            // Get some file names

            string filePath = @"~\tempPdfs\";
            string completeFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filePath);

            var directory = new DirectoryInfo(completeFilePath);
            var fileName = (from f in directory.GetFiles("*.pdf")
                            orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
                            select f).First();
            // Open the output document


            PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfDocument();


            // Open the document to import pages from it..
            PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(fileName.FullName, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

            // Iterate pages
            int count = inputDocument.PageCount;
            for (int idx = 0; idx < count; idx++)
            {
                // Get the page from the external document...
                PdfPage page = inputDocument.Pages[idx];
                // ...and add it to the output document.
                outputDocument.AddPage(page);
            }


            //Create an Empty Page
            PdfPage pdfpage = outputDocument.AddPage();
            pdfpage.Size = PageSize.Letter; // Change the Page Size
            pdfpage.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;// Change the orientation property

            //Get an XGraphics object for drawing
            XGraphics xGrap = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfpage);

            //Create Fonts
            XFont titlefont = new XFont("Calibri", 20, XFontStyle.Regular);
            XFont tableheader = new XFont("Calibri", 15, XFontStyle.Bold);
            XFont bodyfont = new XFont("Calibri", 11, XFontStyle.Regular);

            //Draw the text
            //double x = 250;
            double y = 50;
            //Title Binding
            XTextFormatter textformater = new XTextFormatter(xGrap);  //Used to Hold the Custom text Area

            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                string colorStr = item.Color;

                Regex regex = new Regex(@"rgb\((?<r>\d{1,3}),(?<g>\d{1,3}),(?<b>\d{1,3})\)");
                //regex.Match(colorStr.Replace(" ", ""));
                Match match = regex.Match(colorStr.Replace(" ", ""));
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    int r = int.Parse(match.Groups["r"].Value);
                    int g = int.Parse(match.Groups["g"].Value);
                    int b = int.Parse(match.Groups["b"].Value);

                    y = y + 30;
                    XRect ColorVal = new XRect(85, y, 5, 5);
                    XRect NameVal = new XRect(100, y, 250, 25);

                    var brush = new XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb(r, g, b));
                    xGrap.DrawRectangle(brush, ColorVal);
                    textformater.DrawString(item.Name, bodyfont, XBrushes.Black, NameVal);

                };
            };



            // Save the document...
            var dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("g").Replace('/', '-').Replace(':', '-');
            var filename = string.Format("{0}-{1}.pdf", "PdfSharpResult", dt);
            string physicalPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/completePdfs");
            string relativePath = Path.Combine(physicalPath, filename).Replace("\\", "/");
            var pdfName = relativePath;
            outputDocument.Save(pdfName);
            // ...and start a viewer.
            Process.Start(pdfName);

            return new PDF
            {
                FileName = pdfName,
                FileNameEncoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(pdfName)
            };


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
            return new PDF
            {
                Error = ex.ToString()
            };
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you create the table and assign the rows to it

Comment: just added entire controller

Comment: I don't believe PDFSharp has inbuilt support for tables, and you will need to manage the layout yourself, or use something like MigraDoc

Comment: ok so i can setup layout. how can i do the max row issue. would i split up the string into strings of 15 and somehow work with that?

Comment: Yes, batch your list into 15s, write the first 15 on the left of the first page, the second 15 on the right of the first page, then skip to the next page and continue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where's the problem?

You need an X variable. After 15 rows you reset Y and increment X.

After 30 rows you reset X and Y, add a new page, obtain a new `XGrap` for that page and make a fresh `XTextFormatter` and continue this until the list is done.

A row counter will probably make things easier.

Untested code showing a loop that creates pages as needed and cares for second column:

```
PdfPage pdfpage;
XGraphics xGrap;
XTextFormatter textformater;

//Create Fonts
XFont titlefont = new XFont("Calibri", 20, XFontStyle.Regular);
XFont tableheader = new XFont("Calibri", 15, XFontStyle.Bold);
XFont bodyfont = new XFont("Calibri", 11, XFontStyle.Regular);

//Draw the text
double x = 0;
double y = 50;
//Title Binding

int index = 0;
foreach (var item in data)
{
    if (index % 30 == 0)
    {
        y = 50;
        x = 0;
        // Start a new page.
        //Create an Empty Page
        pdfpage = outputDocument.AddPage();
        pdfpage.Size = PageSize.Letter; // Change the Page Size
        pdfpage.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;// Change the orientation property

        //Get an XGraphics object for drawing
        xGrap = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfpage);
        textformater = new XTextFormatter(xGrap);  //Used to Hold the Custom text Area
    }
    else if (index % 15 == 0)
    {
        // Start a new column.
        y = 50;
        x = 400;
    }
    ++index;

    // Previous code stays here, but must use x in new XRect(...)

    string colorStr = item.Color;

    Regex regex = new Regex(@"rgb\((?<r>\d{1,3}),(?<g>\d{1,3}),(?<b>\d{1,3})\)");
    //regex.Match(colorStr.Replace(" ", ""));
    Match match = regex.Match(colorStr.Replace(" ", ""));
    if (match.Success)
    {
        int r = int.Parse(match.Groups["r"].Value);
        int g = int.Parse(match.Groups["g"].Value);
        int b = int.Parse(match.Groups["b"].Value);

        y = y + 30;
        XRect ColorVal = new XRect(x + 85, y, 5, 5);
        XRect NameVal = new XRect(x + 100, y, 250, 25);

        var brush = new XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb(r, g, b));
        xGrap.DrawRectangle(brush, ColorVal);
        textformater.DrawString(item.Name, bodyfont, XBrushes.Black, NameVal);

    };
};
```

x = 400 is just a guess to get you started. Table headings are missing.

Comment: problem is I am lost. can you make example of what you suggest?

Comment: would i use a while loop?

Comment: I updated my post. No guarantee it compiles, it's just meant to show how I'd do the loop.

Comment: Im having a hard time with the xGrap and textformater variable. I cannot access it from inside the if (match.success) statement

Comment: Create the variables outside the loop, assign them inside the loop. Do not create new variables inside the if statement in the loop.

Comment: did you not create the variables xGrap and textformater outside the loop? and you assigned them inside the first if statement, I cannot assign them in the match.success if statement without pdfpage being declared again

Comment: or did you declare them outside the if statement

Comment: That's what I meant: declare them outside the loop, assign them inside the loop.